# Data cleaning using pandas generating index error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, indexing

I'm using `jupyter notbook` and trying to do some data cleaning using `pandas` dataframe but having some issues regarding `indexing`.

my dataframe is

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df= pd.DataFrame({'ID':{0:'0x1602',1:'0x1603',2:'0x1604',3:'0x1605',4:'0x1606',5:'0x1607',6:'0x1608',7:'0x1609',8:'0x160e',9:'0x160f',10:'0x160f',11:'0x1611',12:'0x1612',13:'0x1613',14:'0x1614',15:'0x1615',16:'0x161a',17:'0x161b',18:'0x161c',19:'0x161d'},'Customer_ID':{0:'CUS_0xd40',1:'CUS_0xd40',2:'CUS_0xd40',3:'CUS_0xd40',4:'CUS_0xd40',5:'CUS_0xd40',6:'CUS_0xd40',7:'CUS_0xd40',8:'CUS_0x21b1',9:'CUS_0x21b1',10:'CUS_0x21b1',11:'CUS_0x21b1',12:'CUS_0x21b1',13:'CUS_0x21b1',14:'CUS_0x21b1',15:'CUS_0x21b1',16:'CUS_0x2dbc',17:'CUS_0x2dbc',18:'CUS_0x2dbc',19:'CUS_0x2dbc'},'Name':{0:'AaronMaashoh',1:'AaronMaashoh',2:'AaronMaashoh',3:'AaronMaashoh',4:'AaronMaashoh',5:'AaronMaashoh',6:'AaronMaashoh',7:np.nan,8:'RickRothackerj',9:'RickRothackerj',10:np.nan,11:'RickRothackerj',12:'RickRothackerj',13:'RickRothackerj',14:'RickRothackerj',15:'RickRothackerj',16:'Langep',17:np.nan,18:'Langep',19:'Langep'},'Num_of_Delayed_Payment':{0:7,1:4,2:7,3:4,4:4,5:np.nan,6:8,7:6,8:4,9:1,10:0,11:3,12:1,13:0,14:4,15:4,16:8,17:6,18:np.nan,19:5}})
df
    ID      Cus_ID      Name           Num_of_Delayed_Payment
0   0x1602  CUS_0xd40   AaronMaashoh    7.0
1   0x1603  CUS_0xd40   AaronMaashoh    4.0
2   0x1604  CUS_0xd40   AaronMaashoh    7.0
3   0x1605  CUS_0xd40   AaronMaashoh    4.0
4   0x1606  CUS_0xd40   AaronMaashoh    4.0
5   0x1607  CUS_0xd40   AaronMaashoh    NaN
6   0x1608  CUS_0xd40   AaronMaashoh    8.0
7   0x1609  CUS_0xd40   NaN             6.0
8   0x160e  CUS_0x21b1  RickRothackerj  4.0
9   0x160f  CUS_0x21b1  RickRothackerj  1.0
10  0x160f  CUS_0x21b1  NaN             0.0
11  0x1611  CUS_0x21b1  RickRothackerj  3.0
12  0x1612  CUS_0x21b1  RickRothackerj  1.0
13  0x1613  CUS_0x21b1  RickRothackerj  0.0
14  0x1614  CUS_0x21b1  RickRothackerj  3.0
15  0x1615  CUS_0x21b1  RickRothackerj  4.0
16  0x161a  CUS_0x2dbc  Langep          8.0
17  0x161b  CUS_0x2dbc  NaN             6.0
18  0x161c  CUS_0x2dbc  Langep          NaN
19  0x161d  CUS_0x2dbc  Langep          6.0
```

After running the below piece of `code cell`

```
df['Num_of_Delayed_Payment'] = df['Num_of_Delayed_Payment'].fillna(df.groupby('Customer_ID')['Num_of_Delayed_Payment'].transform(lambda x:x.mode().iat[0]))
df['Num_of_Delayed_Payment'] = df['Num_of_Delayed_Payment'].str.rstrip('_') 
df["Num_of_Delayed_Payment"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Num_of_Delayed_Payment"])

lower_percentile = 0.01
higher_percentile = 0.87
#returns values at the given quantile within the specified range
low, high = df['Num_of_Delayed_Payment'].quantile([lower_percentile, higher_percentile])
#cap values below low to low
df[df['Num_of_Delayed_Payment'] < low] = low
#cap values above high to high
df[df['Num_of_Delayed_Payment'] > high] = high
```

all the `code cells` which contained similar operation of filling `missing values` generates `Index` error for example see below `code cell`:

`df['Name']=df['Name'].fillna(df.groupby('Customer_ID')['Name'].transform(lambda x:x.mode().iat[0]))`

```
Input In [31], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df['Name']=df['Name'].fillna(df.groupby('Customer_ID')['Name'].transform(lambda x:x.mode().iat[0]))

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py:428, in SeriesGroupBy.transform(self, func, engine, engine_kwargs, *args, **kwargs)
    425 @Substitution(klass="Series")
    426 @Appender(_transform_template)
    427 def transform(self, func, *args, engine=None, engine_kwargs=None, **kwargs):
--> 428     return self._transform(
    429         func, *args, engine=engine, engine_kwargs=engine_kwargs, **kwargs
    430     )

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py:1633, in GroupBy._transform(self, func, engine, engine_kwargs, *args, **kwargs)
   1630 func = com.get_cython_func(func) or func
   1632 if not isinstance(func, str):
-> 1633     return self._transform_general(func, *args, **kwargs)
   1635 elif func not in base.transform_kernel_allowlist:
   1636     msg = f"'{func}' is not a valid function name for transform(name)"

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py:459, in SeriesGroupBy._transform_general(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    456 for name, group in self:
    457     # this setattr is needed for test_transform_lambda_with_datetimetz
    458     object.__setattr__(group, "name", name)
--> 459     res = func(group, *args, **kwargs)
    461     results.append(klass(res, index=group.index))
    463 # check for empty "results" to avoid concat ValueError

Input In [31], in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 df['Name']=df['Name'].fillna(df.groupby('Customer_ID')['Name'].transform(lambda x:x.mode().iat[0]))

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:2221, in _ScalarAccessIndexer.__getitem__(self, key)
   2218         raise ValueError("Invalid call for scalar access (getting)!")
   2220 key = self._convert_key(key)
-> 2221 return self.obj._get_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:1066, in Series._get_value(self, label, takeable)
   1053 """
   1054 Quickly retrieve single value at passed index label.
   1055 
   (...)
   1063 scalar value
   1064 """
   1065 if takeable:
-> 1066     return self._values[label]
   1068 # Similar to Index.get_value, but we do not fall back to positional
   1069 loc = self.index.get_loc(label)

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Expected output should look like

```
    ID      Cus_ID      Name           Num_of_Delayed_Payment
0   0x1602  CUS_0xd40   AaronMaashoh    7.0
1   0x1603  CUS_0xd40   AaronMaashoh    4.0
2   0x1604  CUS_0xd40   AaronMaashoh    7.0
3   0x1605  CUS_0xd40   AaronMaashoh    4.0
4   0x1606  CUS_0xd40   AaronMaashoh    4.0
5   0x1607  CUS_0xd40   AaronMaashoh    4.0
6   0x1608  CUS_0xd40   AaronMaashoh    8.0
7   0x1609  CUS_0xd40   AaronMaashoh    6.0
8   0x160e  CUS_0x21b1  RickRothackerj  4.0
9   0x160f  CUS_0x21b1  RickRothackerj  1.0
10  0x160f  CUS_0x21b1  RickRothackerj  0.0
11  0x1611  CUS_0x21b1  RickRothackerj  3.0
12  0x1612  CUS_0x21b1  RickRothackerj  1.0
13  0x1613  CUS_0x21b1  RickRothackerj  0.0
14  0x1614  CUS_0x21b1  RickRothackerj  3.0
15  0x1615  CUS_0x21b1  RickRothackerj  4.0
16  0x161a  CUS_0x2dbc  Langep          8.0
17  0x161b  CUS_0x2dbc  Langep          6.0
18  0x161c  CUS_0x2dbc  Langep          6.0
19  0x161d  CUS_0x2dbc  Langep          6.0
```

please help me understand the error and the solution.

Thanks

Comment: What is your expected output, and what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark I want to fill the missing values in each column by taking mode (most frequent value present in particular Cus_ID), based on Cus_ID, also I want to cap the outliers using different quantile ranges.